# Performing CRUD operation on each distinct value of a column

Tags: sql-server

what i am trying to achieve is to select distinct values of a column which can be done by

```
select distinct B_id as beauName from tbl_addbill WHERE forUser='sun4269'
```

and then for each distinct B_id i want to execute this query

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_addbill WHERE forUser='sun4269' and bill_no='2015-2016' and B_id='Bhavik Creation-1')
BEGIN
    select 1;
END 
ELSE
BEGIN
    insert into tbl_addbill(bill_no,B_id,amount,tax,amount_paid,forUser,bill_date)
        values 
        (
            '2015-2016',
            'Bhavik Creation-1',
            (
                select COALESCE(sum(amount),0) 
                    from tbl_addbill 
                    where forUser='sun4269' and B_id='BhavikCreation-1' 
                        and bill_date between '2015-04-01' and '2016-03-31'
            ),
            (
                select COALESCE(sum(tax),0)
                    from tbl_addbill
                    where forUser='sun4269' and B_id='BhavikCreation-1' 
                        and bill_date between '2015-04-01' and '2016-03-31'
            ),
            (
                select COALESCE(sum(amount_paid),0) 
                    from tbl_addbill
                    where forUser='sun4269' and B_id='BhavikCreation-1' 
                        and bill_date between '2015-04-01' and '2016-03-31'
            ),
            'sun4269',
            getdate()
        );
    select 2;
END;
```

currently both of my queries are working fine but what i want is combining both of them,as first to select distinct B_id from tbl_addbill and to execute this second query as many times as the distinct list continue.currently my second query works for 'BhavikCreation-1' only and i want to replace it with distinct list and what my second query does is to calculates the SUM of amount,tax,amount_paid for the period of 2015-04-01 to 2016-03-31 and insert a new row into the table

And secondly i am using the same where clause multiple times,is there is any way to reduce it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query with `GROUP BY` clause:

```
insert into tbl_addbill(bill_no,B_id,amount,tax,amount_paid,forUser,bill_date)
    select '2015-2016',
            B_id,
            COALESCE(sum(IIF(bill_date between '2015-04-01' and '2016-03-31', amount,      0)), 0),
            COALESCE(sum(IIF(bill_date between '2015-04-01' and '2016-03-31', tax,         0)), 0),
            COALESCE(sum(IIF(bill_date between '2015-04-01' and '2016-03-31', amount_paid, 0)), 0),
            forUser,
            getdate()
        from tbl_addbill
        where forUser = 'sun4269'
        group by B_id;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    select 1;
ELSE
    select 2;
```

Comment: thanks @ruslan k for the answer but it is not giving the proper results as it is not inserting record for the B_id where the bill is not in the range of the above date range,what i want is to save ('2015-2016','<B_id_name>',0,0,0,'sun4269','<date>') despite of the date range,as it is filtering the results based on the date range....anyways thanks for the answer again

Comment: in short i want to sum the other <B_id> if there is no bills present in the given date range as 0,0,0

Comment: thanx Ruslan K.

Comment: @sam5808, glad to help you